# Web scraping specific information only using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape only specific information from 2 different url's below: From the right side information box table of the presidents. I only want to scrape "Born", "Political Party" and "Website" information. I tried below code but it just gives me all the details. I don't know how to scrape for specific information. Any help to achieve this is very much appreciated.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump
```

Code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
soup

table = soup.findAll('table',{"class":"infobox vcard"})[0]
values =[]
tr = table.findAll(['tr'])  
tr
```

Result:

```
Barack Obama
Obama in 2012
""
44th President of the United States
"In officeJanuary 20, 2009 – January 20, 2017"
Vice President,Joe Biden
Preceded by,George W. Bush
Succeeded by,Donald Trump
United States senatorfrom Illinois
"In officeJanuary 3, 2005 – November 16, 2008Serving with Dick Durbin"
Preceded by,Peter Fitzgerald
Succeeded by,Roland Burris
Member of the Illinois Senatefrom the 13th district
"In officeJanuary 8, 1997 – November 4, 2004"
Preceded by,Alice Palmer
Succeeded by,Kwame Raoul
""
Personal details
Born,"Barack Hussein Obama II (1961-08-04) August 4, 1961 (age 59)Honolulu, Hawaii, U.S."
Political party,Democratic
Spouse(s),Michelle Robinson​ (m. 1992)
Children,MaliaSasha
Mother,Ann Dunham
Father,Barack Obama Sr.
Relatives,See Obama family
Residence,"Kalorama (Washington, D.C.)"
Alma mater,Columbia University (BA)Harvard University (JD)
Awards,Nobel Peace Prize (2009)Profile in Courage Award (2017)
Signature,
Website,Official websiteObama FoundationWhite House Archives
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
targets = ["Born","Political party", "Website"]
values =[]
data = table.select('tr th[scope]')
for dat in data:
    if dat.text in targets:     
        if dat.text == "Website":
            urls = []
            for s in dat.find_next_sibling('td').select('a'):                
                urls.append(s['href'])
            values.append(urls)
        else:
            values.append(dat.find_next_sibling('td').text)

values
```

Output:

```
  ['Barack Hussein Obama II (1961-08-04) August 4, 1961 (age\xa059)Honolulu, Hawaii, U.S.',
 'Democratic',
 ['https://barackobama.com/',
  'https://www.obama.org/',
  'https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov']]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see the website, the side info is the only table with class `infobox` and in order to select specific contents you can use css selectors and `contains` in those selectors

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table',{"class":"infobox vcard"})
born = table.select_one("tr th:contains(Born)").next_sibling
website = table.select_one("tr th:contains(Website)").next_sibling
party = table.select_one("tr th:contains(Political)").next_sibling

print("Born - {}".format(born.get_text(strip=True)))
print("-"*25)
print("Website")
for a in website.find_all("a"):
    print(a.get_text() + " - " + a["href"])
print("-"*25)
print("Political Party")
print(party.find("a").get_text() + " - " + party.find("a")["href"])
```

Output:

```
Born - Barack Hussein Obama II(1961-08-04)August 4, 1961(age 59)Honolulu,Hawaii, U.S.
-------------------------
Website
Official website - https://barackobama.com/
Obama Foundation - https://www.obama.org/
White House Archives - https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov
-------------------------
Political Party
Democratic - /wiki/Democratic_Party_(United_States)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am wondering what if the information is in <td> < a href> for example from this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London